# Uninstall Novell Client service from Microsoft login

Tags: windows

My mom gave me my dad's laptop after he passed away.  He has Novell Client Services as a log on to the PC. I need to remove this service. Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 1):

A step-by-step instruction for Windows NT/2000/XP/2003 is available there: http://www.novell.com/support/kb/doc.php?id=3979598